# Scraping text from a unity based program

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, hook

I am trying to scrape a text box in a game that outputs various information such as resources all players are receiving during the game. I would like to scrape this text so I can use the information.

I went down the road of trying to use Spy++ to get the window handle of the text box, but the entire program only has a single handle. Gathering more info, I found out it is using the Unity game engine

Am I out of luck because the text box doesn't have it's own handle? Is there a Unity way of hooking into programs to get messages?

I would like to avoid going down the road of using rapid screenshots and OCR, since it would require for the text box tab to always be showing

Comment: Like most programs you can only hook in and get messages really when someone wants you to.  If Unity is however sending and receiving web data you can potentially intercept or recreate that

Comment: Unity scipts are written in C#, so use ILSpy instead, you might find someting

Comment: @zambari Good idea, I shall have a look around

Comment: @BugFinder I was going to go the MITM approach, but this game also features local offline mode, and I would preferably want it to work for both. However, I may try that way if I hit a dead end.